# Odd behaviour from Java IDE (NetBeans)

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, ide

I'm using Java and NetBeans to create an application and I seem to be getting some varying results when it comes to making and changing the GUI using the editor.

My design in the editor looks like this:

[image: Editor view]

When I click on the icon to give me a demonstration of what it would actually look like I see this:

[image: Demo view]

Notice that the panel to the right of the GUI has moved down and pushed the text box down as a result.

Now when I come to run the application itself I see this:

[image: Running application]

I may be too used to the way in which the Visual Studio IDE works in the fact that everything generally stays where you put it, am I missing some sort of hidden trick or property that is throwing everything off?

Thanks for your time.

**Edit:**

Code for the components - http://pastebin.com/FHF2fBEw

Comment: Please post the source code for the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this kind of problems before, not always the visual designer ( `Matisse` in this case)  gives you the same result at different window resolutions. After fighting with several issues like the one you are having now, I decided to use [JGoodies Forms](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/).

I would suggest you to use it if you want to have control over your GUIs without a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of layout are you using? I suggest a `java.awt.GridBag` layout for what you're doing.